# How to get current user ID

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a web page and when you sign up and login you need to complete your information (name, last name, career, gender).
I've created a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[añadirinfocontacto]
    @id int,@apellidoP nvarchar(50),@apellidoM nvarchar(50),@nombre nvarchar(50),@idEspecialidad int,@sexo nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    if(@id=1)
    begin
    update Tbl_alumnos set nombre=@nombre,apellido_paterno=@apellidoP,apellido_materno=@apellidoM,id_especialidad=@idEspecialidad,sexo=@sexo where id_usuarios=@id
    end
    else
    if(@id=2)
    begin
    update Tbl_Maestros set nombre=@nombre,apellido_paterno=@apellidoP,apellido_materno=@apellidoM,id_especialidad=@idEspecialidad,sexo=@sexo where id_usuarios=@id
    end
    else
    begin
    update Tbl_Administradores set nombre=@nombre,apellido_paterno=@apellidoP,apellido_materno=@apellidoM,id_especialidad=@idEspecialidad,sexo=@sexo where id_usuarios=@id
    end

END
```

Code:

```
public static EntUsuario Actualizar(int idU,string nombre, string Apellidop,string ApellidoM,int IdEsp,string sexo)
{
    EntUsuario obj = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    try
    {
        Conexion cn = new Conexion( );
        SqlConnection cnx = cn.conectar();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("añadirinfocontacto", cnx);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idU);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellidoP", Apellidop);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellidoM", ApellidoM);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idEspecialidad", IdEsp);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", sexo);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cnx.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnx.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        obj = null;

    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    return obj;

}
```

And the Cick button event

```
protected void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guid guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            EntUsuario obj = GbUsuario.Actualizar(Convert.ToInt32(guid),txtNombre.Text,txtApP.Text,txtApM.Text,Convert.ToInt32(dpEspecialidad.SelectedValue),RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);

        }
```

I want to get de user's ID but I don't know what to do, I've read about Session["user_id"], Membership.getUser, I also read that I need to configure web.config.

If I use the sample code above I use Membership.getUser but appears an error saying that it couldn't conect to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here`You can get the current user with the following code:

```
var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
```

You can force users to log in by adding this to the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
         <authorization>
             <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```